# Minimising the number of bus changes in a matrix

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, backtracking

```
[ 42,  45,  47,  x,  x] -> stop1 to stop2
[ 45,  47,  42,  88,  x] -> stop2 to stop3
[ 21,  77,  42,  x,  x] -> stop3 to stop4
[ 22,  47,  42,  88,  x] -> stop4 to stop5
[ 23,  47,  42,  x,  x] -> stop5 to stop6
[ 24,  47,  42,  8,  91] -> stop6 to stop7
[ 25,  13,  42,  3,  84] -> stop7 to stop8
[ 26,  10,  11,  4,  54] -> stop8 to stop9
[ 27,  9,  8,  88,   71] -> stop9 to stop10
```

`x is there just for formatting. The first row means that there are only three buses from stop1 to stop2(42, 45, 47).`

I have this matrix like structure where each row represents the buses going from one stop to another. I need to minimize the number of bus changes a person has to make to go from stop1 to stop10.

For example one of the output should be 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 26, 27 another can be 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 10, 9. If the number of changes is more than three I can discard the result.

What's the most optimal way to achieve this as brute forcing through it is pretty unefficient right now?

Comment: I think this is doable by forming a graph with bus stops as vertices and different buses as edges between these vertices, let me try it, seems very interesting to me :)

Comment: @zenwraight This Is actually an outcome of  a graph db query. We needed to reduce the number of edges between the nodes so though if we can process the initial result (the above matrix) to minimise the number bus changes a person has to make.

Comment: Ohk by the way in the two outputs you have missed the bus route from stop 7 to stop 8... check it, so you want a way to preprocess this input so that the computation time is reduced for the graph db query right ? hmm

Comment: Thanks, Corrected it. Rather Postprocessing the data being spit out form our db query and yep we are trying to speed up our graph db queries. :)

Comment: What is `x` above? Another bus?

Comment: It's just for formatting the matrix so it looks all nice and pretty. Thanks, edited the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go through the array once, and keep a set of buses that are common to the visited stops. As soon as none such buses can be found, take the previous set, choose one bus from it, and fill the result with that bus for that many stops.

Then put all buses at the current stop in the set, and repeat the operation for the subsequent stops, ...etc.

Here is the algorithm coded in ES6 JavaScript. It uses a `Set` to allow constant-time access to the items (buses) it stores.

```js
// Helper function: given a reduced set of buses, and a count,
//   add one of those buses as the bus to take during that many stops
function addToResult(common, count, result) {
    let bus = common.values().next().value; // pick any available bus
    while (count > 0) {
        result.push(bus);
        count--;
    }
}

// Main algorithm
function getBusRide(stops) {
    if (stops.length === 0) return [];

    let result = [],
        count = 0,
        common;
    for (let buses of stops) {
        if (count == 0) { // First iteration only
            common = new Set(buses); // all buses are candidate
            count = 1;
        } else {
            let keep = new Set();
            for (let bus of buses) {
                // Only keep buses as candidate when they 
                //     are still served here
                if (common.has(bus)) keep.add(bus);
            }
            if (keep.size == 0) { // Need to change bus
                addToResult(common, count, result);
                count = 0;
                keep = new Set(buses); // all buses are candidate
            }
            common = keep;
            count++;
        }
    }
    addToResult(common, count, result);
    return result;
}

// Sample input
const stops = [
    [ 42,  45,  47],
    [ 45,  47,  42,  88],
    [ 21,  77,  42],
    [ 22,  47,  42,  88],
    [ 23,  47,  42],
    [ 24,  47,  42,  8,  91],
    [ 25,  13,  42,  3,  84],
    [ 26,  10,  11,  4,  54],
    [ 27,  9,  8,  88,   71]
];

// Apply the algorithm
console.log(getBusRide(stops));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

This algorithm runs in *O(n)* where *n* is the total number of values in the input, so in the example *n = 37*.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. I was aiming for something like this.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by modeling it as a graph search.

Imagine you're a person and you're trying to get from point A to point B. The information most relevant to you is

1. where you currently are, and
2. which bus line, if any, you are currently on.

You can therefore model a person's state as a pair of a location (a bus stop) and a bus line (which might be "not on a line" when they start or finish). So create a graph with one node for each combination of a location and a bus line.

The edges in this graph will correspond to changes in state. You can change state either by

1. staying on your current bus line and going somewhere, or
2. switching bus lines.

If you're currently on a bus line, you can stay on that line to move from one location to the next if the line goes from the first location to the second. So create edges ((location1, *line*), (location2, *line*)) if bus line *line* goes from location1 to location2. This doesn't involve a transfer, so give this edge a cost of 0.

Alternatively, you can always get off of a bus or go from being off a bus to being on a bus. So add an edge ((location, *line*), (location, *free*)) for each line and each location (you always have the option to get off of a bus line) and give it cost 0, since this doesn't involve changing lines. Similarly, add edges ((location, *free*), (location, *line*)) for each bus line *line* available at the given location. Give it cost 1 to indicate that this requires you to get on a bus.

Now, imagine you find a path from (point A, *free*) to (point B, *free*) in this graph. This corresponds to getting on and off of a series of buses that start you at point A and end at point B, and the cost will be the number of different buses that you ended up getting on. If you run a shortest paths algorithm in this graph (say, Dijkstra's algorithm), you'll find the path from the start to end point that minimizes the number of bus transfers!